# android sqllite not fetching the values Second time

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have created a Listview using sqlite. ( In my XML file i have 1 listview and 1 edittext. If i type name partially in the edittext then it should check against the sqllite database and brings the data. Initially the Listbox shows only one entry from SQLITE database. If i typed something then it should check against the database and display that data in the Listview.

My App showing one record first time, but when i entered the character in textbox i am invoking the select query, but its giving the below error:

```
03-05 23:19:12.926: E/Database(203): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.androidhive.androidlistviewwithsearch/databasessample", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
03-05 23:19:13.005: E/MainActivity(203): Could not create or Open the database
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.androidhive.androidlistviewwithsearch;
import com.androidhive.androidlistviewwithsearch.DBHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String tableName = DBHelper.tableName;
    private SQLiteDatabase newDB;

    // List view
    private ListView lv;
        // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;

    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Listview Data
        String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                                "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                                "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        openAndQueryDatabase();
        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, results);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        int itemPosition     = arg2;

                        // ListView Clicked item value
                        String  itemValue    = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                         // Show Alert 
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                           "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                           .show();     

            }

       });        
        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                         "Position :"+ cs +"  ListItem : "  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                         .show();
                 FetchQueryDatabase(cs);

                //MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); 
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
    }

    private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
        try {
            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
            newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName, Age FROM " +
                    tableName +
                    " LIMIT 1", null);
            Log.d("ingu","vanthen1");

            if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
                        int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
                        results.add("Name: " + firstName + ",Age: " + age);
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                } 
            }           
        } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
        } finally {
            if (newDB != null) 
                newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
                newDB.close();
        }

    }

    private void FetchQueryDatabase(CharSequence cs) {
        try {
            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
            newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            String val=cs.toString();
            Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName, Age FROM " +
                     " where FirstName LIKE ? '%"+val+"%'", null);

            if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
                        int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
                        String age1 = age+"";
                        Log.d("age", age1);
                        results.add("Name: " + firstName + ",Age: " + age);
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                } 
            }           
        } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
        } 


        finally {
            if (newDB != null) 
                newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
                newDB.close();
        }
    }
}
```

DBHelper.Java

```
package com.androidhive.androidlistviewwithsearch;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public SQLiteDatabase DB;
    public String DBPath;
    public static String DBName = "sample";
    public static final int version = '1';
    public static Context currentContext;
    public static String tableName = "Resource";


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBName, null, version);
        currentContext = context;
        DBPath = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases";
        createDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void createDatabase() {
        boolean dbExists = checkDbExists();

        if (dbExists) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            DB = currentContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DBName, 0, null);
            DB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                    tableName +
                    " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR," +
                    " Country VARCHAR, Age INT(3));");

            DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    tableName +
                    " Values ('M','shumi','India',25);");
            DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    tableName +
                    " Values ('C','sarah','India',25);");
            DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    tableName +
                    " Values ('D','Lavya','USA',20);");
            DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    tableName +
                    " Values ('V','Avi','EU',25);");
            DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    tableName +
                    " Values ('T','Shenoi','Bangla',25);");
            DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    tableName +
                    " Values ('L','Lamha','Australia',20);");
        }


    }

    private boolean checkDbExists() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DBPath + DBName;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database does't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need `createDatabase` and `checkDbExists` methods? `onCreate` and `onUpdate` methods will do all the needed stuff

Comment: any example, how i can do that, becz i am new to creating this sqlite database